# Исключение во время анимации

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, анимация

Имеется некоторый ListView, в последней колонке которого содержится кнопка, по клику на которую должна произойти анимация.

1) Если не указывать Storyboard.TargetName="someButton", то анимация срабатывает, фон кнопки, на которую мы кликнули, меняется.

2) Если указан Storyboard.TargetName="someButton" (мы пытаемся управлять фоном другой кнопки), то где-то вылетает исключение и пишет "Приложение находится в режиме приостановки выполнения".

Из этого напрашивается вывод, что управлять состоянием других элементов не получается, однако это не так, поскольку другая кнопка, которая НЕ находится в ListView (не сгенерирована на каждую строчку), успешно управляет фоном других элементов. Подозреваю, что дело в том, что кнопки в ListView генерируются динамически в зависимости от количества объектов в ItemSourse, но это как-то странно..
Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией? Заранее спасибо

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}">            
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                ....
                <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="3D модель">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}">
                                <Image Width="30" Source="/Resources/Images/eye.png" />
                                <Button.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>                                                                                                                
                                               <ColorAnimation 
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="someButton" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                                To="Red" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:2" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Button.Triggers>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: `Storyboard.TargetName="someButton"` ищет `someButton` внутри `DataTemplate` поэтому если кнопка `someButton` находится вне `DataTemplate` он ее соответственно не найдет.
Возможно получится если попробовать так: `Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, ElementName=someButton, Path=Background.Color}"`

Comment: За наводку спасибо, проблема действительно именно в том, что я пытаюсь вызвать анимацию элемента вне DataTemplate.
В таком случае, при открытии окна сразу вылетает исключение.. Если просто указать Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=someButton}", то всё работает. Однако, если указать там имя какого-нибудь comboBox, то всё валится.. Странно

Comment: Видел в сети решение https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b173047-f7ed-4226-ac50-32fbfeedc603/binding-element-to-storyboard-target-which-is-outside-datatemplate?forum=wpf

Предлагают при клике на кнопку менять какое-то свойство во ViewModel, а на нужный элемент, который необходимо анимировать, повесить DataTrigger. Но что-то мне кажется, должно быть более изящное решение

Comment: Ну со свойством во viewmodel вариант, но тогда анимации не будет. А насчет падения, если после того как ошибка вылезет в студии нажать продолжить, то в Output будет написано подробное описание ошибки, по ней можно сделать вывод в какой момент и почему конкретно она возникает.
Но это однозначно проблема с биндингом. Он либо не находит этот элемент, так как  ищет в другом контексте, либо не то свойство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне подсказали в комментариях, проблема действительно была в том, что я обращался из DataTemplate к внешним контролам напрямую, а необходимо было использовать Binding по ElementName. Примеры анимаций:

```
<Storyboard>
        <services:GridLengthAnimation
            Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=FirstRow}"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            From="280"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:0.2" />
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=VersionsComboBox}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.3" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimation 
           Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=someButton}" 
           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
           To="Red" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:2" />
</Storyboard>
```